# Why does apt think it needs this extra dependency?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm working on some machine setup instructions, and I was surprised to find out that `apt-get install A B` can behave differently than `apt-get install A && apt-get install B`.

My specific example is `A == openjdk-7-jdk` and `B == ant`.

So, `openjdk-7-jdk` depends on `openjdk-7-jre-headless`, which satisfies `ant`'s dependency  `java6-runtime-headless`. But if you install them as `apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk ant`, APT doesn't seem to figure this out and installs `default-jre-headless`. But if you install `openjdk-7-jdk` prior to installing `ant`, its dependency is satisfied and all is good.

APT is usually smart enough to figure this sort of thing out, so why can't it do so in this case? I'd like to have a better understanding as to why it works this way, so this sort of thing doesn't trip me up again in the future.

Comment: Looking at my apt cache I see that openjdk-7-jdk 7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1ubuntu2 depends upon openjdk-7-jre, which in turn depends upon openjdk-7-jre-headless, so this dependency is indirect. ant depends directly on default-jre-headless. I'm using Precise. I'm only guessing but apt-get could either arbitrarily start with ant, or start with level 1 dependencies and then go to level 2 dependencies. In any case, if you care about the final configuration of packages (want openjdk-7-jre-headless over default-..-..) specifying them specifically and individually is probably the best way to control that.

Comment: Are you still interested in that question?

Comment: @guntbert Sure, although I've resigned myself into believing that there is no reason; it's just the way it is.

Comment: To see how the APT resolver works, look at `apt-get install -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true package1 package2...`. That might give you a hint why it's working that way.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that there is some kind of "weight" system playing here:

```
$ aptitude why ant openjdk-7-jdk
p   ant                 Recommends ant-optional       
p   ant-optional        Suggests   libgnumail-java    
p   libgnumail-java     Suggests   libgnumail-java-doc
p   libgnumail-java-doc Recommends default-jdk-doc    
p   default-jdk-doc     Depends    openjdk-7-doc      
p   openjdk-7-doc       Suggests   openjdk-7-jdk
```

As you can see `ant` depends of `openjdk-7-jdk` due a complicated and intricated amounts of suggestions, recommendations and dependency, while when using `openjdk-6-jdk` the dependency is more direct:

```
$ aptitude why ant openjdk-6-jdk
p   ant           Suggests default-jdk | java-compiler | java-sdk
p   openjdk-6-jdk Provides java-sdk
```

Of course `aptitude` methods of dependency resolution, could be different of `apt-get`'s. BTW, running a simulation of ant without openjdk-7-jdk installed don't pulled openjdk-6-jdk:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ant
[sudo] password for braiam: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ant-optional
Suggested packages:
  default-jdk java-compiler java-sdk ant-gcj ant-doc liboro-java junit
  libregexp-java jython antlr libbcel-java libjdepend-java libgnumail-java
  libcommons-net-java libjsch-java javacc ant-optional-gcj
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ant ant-optional
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,234 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,041 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Maybe if you use the same methods as I did, you could figure out more, since I'm using Debian testing right now and repositories could have changed in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it has defaults for satisfying a dependency, so if that dependency has not been satisfied prior to installing a package, it installs the dependency and then installs the requested package.

This could also just be a large bug, though.

Either way, hope that helps.